# how to use excel data with selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

i am on Beginning stage in **SELENIUM**. Now, i am trying functional testing on selenium web-driver. As driving EXCEL data is very essential on functional testing, i am struggling a lot in this are. How to use Excel data?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe you could post that code so we could help you with that.

Comment: You can use JXL or POI library for manipulation of excel from java, If you are using different binding language, you need look out for library in same for manipulation excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be need to read data from excel using (apache POI) Java and perform some actions using webdriver.
Below URL will help you out
[Excel Operations using Apache POI](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/)

[Some more references](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/apachepoi-tutorials)

[Even more detailed](http://www.guru99.com/all-about-excel-in-selenium-poi-jxl.html)

Comment: thank you so much!!  Is any any easy options other than Installing POI?   In Eclipse Mars they given option as Functional Testing where i can connect EXCEL.,   can you say about this?

Comment: I am not aware of connect EXCEL in Mars, but better for beginner to use java.io.FileInputStream which I think Mars will be using it internally.
The references provided in answer are enough for that and you can Up Vote my answer if details gives us solution.

Answer (score 0):

Beginners in Selenium Python,

You can use `openpyxl` library

To install:

> pip install openpyxl